# set_time_limit does not respect exec() calls

Tags: php, extjs

I have an application where I can make calls, that will take anywhere from 60-90 seconds to return. I did set_time_limit(0), but because I am doing an exec() command, it doesn't take that into account.

So I modify these two values in my php.ini and restarted Apache (CentOS)

```
max_execution_time = 300     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 300    ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
```

But I make the call in my app, and time it, and it is still dying at 30 seconds? What are my options?

Comment: make sure that there is no errors/endless loop in your code.

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct php.ini file you edited?

Comment: Yes, I created a phpinfo() page, and when I pulled it up, it shows the values for those parameters on the page

Comment: The php code / page only executes this exec(), and I tested the command separately, and it works great. I limited the script to do less work so it doesn't take more than 30 sec, and it worked fine and returned the correct results. Something is blocking these changes I have made maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own fault. I did not set the time out in the Ajax.Request. It was the browser timing it out, not the server.